# How do I create an if statement to show and hide my footer section when the correct number of elements are clicked

Tags: jquery

I need help with an if statement to hide and show my footer. The purpose for this is, so I have one button selected from the div with an id of price and 3 buttons from the div with an id of spec selected. Once all are selected, the footer appears. If any are deselected, the footer disappears.

Currently, I'm seeing if the length of li.active > 0 for #price div and the length of the #spec div > 1. If it is than i display the footer as block.

It doesn't seem to be working, Help

```js
$(document).on('click', '#price ul li', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#price ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');    
    }
});
var selectedCount = $('#spec ul li').siblings().filter('.active').length;

$(document).on('click', '#spec ul li', function() {
    
    if (selectedCount < 3 || $(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    } else {
      console.log('only 3 can be selected');
    }   
  });

  if ($('#price ul li.active').length > 0 && $('#spec ul li.active').length > 1) {
    $("footer").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $("footer").css("display", "none");
  }
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "samsungOne";
  src: url(fonts/SamsungOne-400.woff2);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400; }
@font-face {
  font-family: "samsungOne-700";
  src: url(fonts/SamsungOne-700.woff2);
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700; }
@font-face {
  font-family: "samsungSharp";
  src: url(fonts/SamsungSharpSansBd.woff);
  font-style: bold;
  font-weight: 700; }
* {
  margin: 0; }
  * body {
    background-color: #fafafa; }
    * body h2, * body h3, * body p {
      margin: 0; }

header {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #d4d4d4;
  padding: 50px 0 40px 0; }
  header .content-container h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "samsungSharp", Arial;
    font-size: 26px; }
  header .content-container p {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "SamsungOne", Arial;
    font-weight: bold; }

main {
  padding: 45px 20px 30px 20px; }
  main .content-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto; }
    main .content-container h3 {
      margin: 0 0 18px;
      font-family: "SamsungOne-700", Arial;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px; }
    main .content-container .content-row {
      width: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-bottom: 45px; }
      main .content-container .content-row ul {
        padding: 0px; }
        main .content-container .content-row ul li {
          list-style: none;
          display: inline; }
          main .content-container .content-row ul li button {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 1px 4px 1px #e5e5e5;
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 1% 15px 1%;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 25px 0px; }
            main .content-container .content-row ul li button img {
              height: 50px; }
            main .content-container .content-row ul li button h3 {
              margin-bottom: 6px;
              font-family: "SamsungOne-700", Arial;
              font-size: 18px; }
            main .content-container .content-row ul li button p {
              font-family: "SamsungOne", Arial;
              color: #b5b1b1; }
          main .content-container .content-row ul li button:hover {
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #000000; }
          main .content-container .content-row ul li button:focus {
            outline: none; }
        main .content-container .content-row ul li.active button {
          border: 3px solid #142c98; }
          main .content-container .content-row ul li.active button p {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #828282; }
        main .content-container .content-row ul li.active button:hover {
          box-shadow: none; }

#price button img {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 6px; }
@media screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  #price button {
    width: 29.2%; }
    #price button img {
      height: 15px; }
    #price button p {
      font-size: 13px; } }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #spec button {
    width: 47%; }
    #spec button p {
      font-size: 13px; } }
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  #spec button {
    width: 100%; } }

footer {
  display: none;
  background-color: #000000; }
  footer .content-container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: auto; }
    footer .content-container p {
      text-align: center;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 0px;
      font-family: "SamsungOne", Arial; }
      footer .content-container p img {
        position: relative;
        top: 8px;
        width: 28px; }
      footer .content-container p span {
        font-weight: bold; }
      footer .content-container p button {
        background-color: #162992;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 15px 40px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 25px;
        margin: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 12px; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Samsung</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-container">
            <h2>Find your ideal Galaxy A Series phone</h2>
            <p>Select you preferences below and we'll recommend the right phone for you.</p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="price" class="content-container">
            <h3>How much would you like to spend?</h3>
            <div class="content-row">
                <ul> 
                    <li class="">   
                        <button type="button" >
                            <img src="assets/£.svg" height="30px" alt="Pound sign" />
                            <p>Upto £219</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/££.svg" height="30px" alt="Two pound signs" />
                            <p>£309-£359</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/£££.svg" height="30px" alt="Three pound signs" />
                            <p>£489+</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="spec" class="content-container">
            <h3>Pick the 3 features most important to you</h3>
            <div class="content-row">
                <ul>
                    <li class="">
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Screen.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Screen size</h3>
                            <p>Ejoying films, games and photos</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Camera.png" width="50px" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Camera</h3>
                            <p>Taking amazing photos and selfies</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Storage.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Storage</h3>
                            <p>Space for music, movies and games</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Battery.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Battery life</h3>
                            <p>Power to keep up with busy lives</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">   
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Performace.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Perfomance</h3>
                            <p>Run multiple apps at once with ease</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">    
                        <button>
                            <img src="assets/Gaming.svg" alt="Mobile phone screen" />
                            <h3>Gaming</h3>
                            <p>Playing graphics intensive games</p>
                        </button>
                    </li>    
                </ul>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-container">
            <p><img src="assets/thick.png" alt="tick" />
            <span>It's a match!</span> We've found a great Galaxy A phone for you
            <button>View phone</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet with relevant HTML

Comment: Add this to your functions `$("footer").toggle($('#price ul li.active').length >0 && $('#spec ul li.active').length== 3)`

Comment: you can simply declare it as global variables and then use those variables in your functions as well outside the functions.

Comment: but in global variables will always be accessible and values in it too, so you have to first empty those variables before using for another task in the functions.